# Why does std::atomic constructor behave different in C++14 and C++17

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17, stdatomic

I'm working in a project with C++11 and I tried following code

```
#include <atomic>

struct A {
    std::atomic_int idx = 1;

};

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

I get the compiler error

```
error: use of deleted function 'std::__atomic_base<_IntTp>::__atomic_base(const std::__atomic_base<_IntTp>&) [with _ITp = int]'
 std::atomic_int idx = 1;
                       ^
```

The same result is with C++14. When I switch to C++17 it works: [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Fa6J9GdjCUvMosdQ)

I checked cppreference for differences:

- [`std::atomic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic)
- [`std::atomic<T>::operator=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator%3D)
- [`std::atomic<T>::atomic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/atomic)

But there is no difference documented between C++14 and C++17. Why does it work with C++17 and not with C++14?

Comment: What compiler/standard library/platform do you use ?

Comment: @VictorGubin I tried with Clang and GCC on Linux (Wandbox). I tried different versions.

Comment: You can simplify the MCVE to just a local in `main` (or any function, no need for it to be `main`), instead of a struct constructor.  Clang gives a similar error message, being more explicit that it's trying to use a deleted *copy* constructor instead of initializer or plain constructor: https://godbolt.org/z/SBGf9w with libc++

Comment: @PeterCordes I wasn't sure if this error is related to class initialization.

Comment: Getting the same error message for a simpler [mcve] proves it isn't.  I wasn't sure either until I tried it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Because in C++17 there is a guaranteed RVO. In C++14 statements like `Foo x = Foo(args)` and `Foo x (args)` are technically not the same, but they are in C++17.

```
struct Foo {
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
};

int main() {
    // Works in C++17 and C++20, fails in C++14 and before
    Foo foo = Foo(); 
}
```

You can read more about this here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

In particular the section `(since C++17)`:

> T x = T(T(f())); // only one call to default constructor of T, to
>   initialize x

To make C++14 code work, you can use

```
std::atomic_int idx { 1 };
```